# Datatables get value of searchable on a column

Tags: datatables

I have created a datatable with following code:

```js
userTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                processing: true,
                ajax: {
                        url: "{!! route('listOfUsersAjax') !!}",
                        type: "GET",
                        dataSrc: function ( json ) {
                          //console.log(json);;
                            for ( var i=0, ien=json.data.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                                if (json.data[i].is_manager == 1){
                                    json.data[i].is_manager = 'Yes';
                                }
                                else {
                                    json.data[i].is_manager = 'No';
                                }
                            }
                            return json.data;
                        }
                    },
                columns: [
                    {
                        className:      'details-control',
                        orderable:      false,
                        searchable:     false,
                        data:           null,
                        defaultContent: ''
                    },
                    { name: 'id', data: 'id' },
                    { name: 'name', data: 'name' },
                    { name: 'email', data: 'email' },
                    { name: 'is_manager', data: 'is_manager'},
                    { name: 'region', data: 'region' },
                    { name: 'country', data: 'country' },
                    { name: 'domain', data: 'domain' },
                    { name: 'management_code', data: 'management_code' },
                    { name: 'job_role', data: 'job_role' },
                    { name: 'employee_type', data: 'employee_type' },
                    {
                        name: 'actions',
                        data: null,
                        sortable: false,
                        searchable: false,
                        render: function (data) {
                            var actions = '';
                            actions += '<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">';
                            actions += '<button data-toggle="tooltip" title="view" id="'+data.id+'" class="buttonView btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button>';
                            actions += '<button data-toggle="tooltip" title="edit" id="'+data.id+'" class="buttonUpdate btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>';
                            actions += '<button data-toggle="tooltip" title="delete" id="'+data.id+'" class="buttonDelete btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>';
                            actions += '</div>';
                            return actions;
                        }
                    }
                    ],
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        "targets": [1,3,4], "visible": false, "searchable": false
                    }
                    ],
                order: [[2, 'asc']],
                initComplete: function () {
                    this.api().columns().every(function () {
                        var column = this;
                        //console.log(userTable);
                        // Now we need to skip the first column as it is used for the drawer...
                        if(column[0][0] == '0' || column[0][0] == '11'){return true;};
                        var input = document.createElement("input");
                        $(input).appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                        .on('keyup change', function () {
                            column.search($(this).val(), false, false, true).draw();
                        });
                    });
                }
            } );
```

At the end, you can see that I have put a initComplete to have search columns to be at the bottom of each column.

I don't need to have a search when the column is not searchable, for example, first column and last one because it is not searchable. I am using the number of the column and returning true so that it doesn't create it but I would like something more dynamic and have an if column searchable is false then return true that way I don't need to specify the number of the column.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *do* have the `columns` definition available through `this.api().init().columns`. So all you have to do is to evaluate if a columns `searchable` explicit is set to `false` (not defining searchable or not defining the column at all means true, since this is the default) :

```js
initComplete: function() {
  var columns = this.api().init().columns;
  this.api().columns().every(function(index) {
    if (!columns[index] || columns[index].searchable) {
       // column is searchable
     } else {
       // column is not searchable           
     }
   })  
 }
```

Comment: Not working. But when I do a console.log(index) it is telling me undefined

Comment: Ok, I found that you cannot use index in function(index), instead, you have to definve it this way: var column = this; index = column[0][0];

Comment: @Richard Sorry for the late response, this is the fiddle I made when I wrote the answer -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/933/** I suspect the reason for your missing `index` is that it was [**first introduced in 1.10.8**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns().every()#Type) I did not think about that, you probably use an older version of dataTables.